# Can we crawl an office365 shared maibox using PHP?

Tags: php, web-crawler, imap, office365

i'm using the bellow code to connect to a normal office365 mailbox , but I wonder how to do (is it even possible?) with [shared mailboxes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150498(v=exchg.150).aspx) as they are not associated with a username/password

```
private $_server="xxx.outlook.com";
private $_port="993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert";
private $_path="INBOX";
private $_mbox=FALSE;
private $_imap_username="user@domain.com";
private $_imap_password="passwd";

$connection="{".$this->_server.":".$this->_port."}".$this->_path;
$this->_mbox=imap_open($connection, $this->_imap_username, $this->_imap_password);
$messages=imap_search($this->_mbox, 'FROM "person@otherdomain.com"');
```

Does anybody got a clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access shared mailbox using a special username.

Example - Settings for IMAP Configuration :

- EMAIL ADDRESS: info@contoso.com (shared mailbox)
- PASSWORD: John Smith's Password (user's password)
- IMAP SERVER: outlook.office365.com (imap server)
- SMTP SERVER: smtp.office365.com (smtp server)
- USERNAME: john.smith@contoso.com\info@contoso.com (user\shared mailbox)

Source : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/6369118f-7dee-4728-ac1c-a0c706b3d290/office-365-exchange-online-how-to-access-a-shared-mailbox-using-thunderbird-or-other-imap-client?forum=onlineservicesexchange

Comment: thank you very much , I had to use the shared mailbox alias in the username